# Where to ask about the "Three Books On Occult Philosophy"?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

As I had... frequently... ended up misplacing my questions onto sites that they do not belong on, I am going to take the safe road and simply ask where I may ask the question.

My question is related to the Three Books On Occult Philosophy, written by Heinrich Cornelius Agrippa, a scholar and writer who studied such topics, from Germany.

It was stated that the three main fields of magic are Elemental Magic, Celestial Magic, and Intellectual Magic. This becomes even more confusing to be due to the actual titles of the books apparently calling them Natural Magic, Celestial Magic, and Ceremonial Magic.

So far, I have been unable to figure the differences between them, and I wanted to know who would have knowledge of this.

Due to this having been actual factual information back then, I do not think that mythology or fantasy would be the proper places to put the question, but the philosophy page itself does not seem like it would have the answers that I need to find.

My question, to put it bluntly, is where this question is likely to be answered honestly without saying it does not belong?

Comment: Uhh...[philosophy.se]?

Comment: Since these books were published in 1533, it _might_ be on-topic on History.SE . Hopefully someone more familiar with History.SE can tell us for certain.

Comment: @ale I just figured that someone on the Philosophy page will not take it very well. "Occult Philosophy" is technically not a real discipline like logic or ethics, so I do not know if they are going to be happy with it.

Comment: That Paranormal site idea that @kenorb mentioned seems really good, but in the meantime, it looks like I have to choose somewhere else if I want my question answered sooner than that.

Also, and not to blow smoke, but how did my question get **_downvoted_** when all I asked... using the site recommendation tag on the _Meta_, no less... was where to post it?

Comment: You asked in the right place. I'm not sure why it was downvoted, but you also got upvotes.

Comment: It's entirely possible there there _isn't_ a Stack Exchange site where this would be suitable.

Comment: <sigh>... Oh joy...

Answer (score 1):

If the book is categorized in sci-fi category, you can ask at [Science Fiction & Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/). You can also try asking at [Literature.SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/).

If you won't find suitable place, based on the fact that the book is more occult/esoteric topic oriented, there is a [Paranormal proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/114464/paranormal), where that kind of questions can be on-topic once the site will become public.